# jQuery UI sortable on DIV makes scrollbars unusable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

In the meanwhile I have made some additional test and limited the core of my origin issue:

- Problem exists with Firefox 33 (OSX, Win 7)
- In Safari (OSX) it works.
- In IE 11 (Win 7) it works partly (cursor activity is not released properly ..)

See test code below.

My problem is:
When the text is longer than the defined div size, the scrollbar appears as it should.
But due to sortable of Main div, when I try to move scrollbar with the mouse, I move the div instead.
Of course I can still scroll in inner div using mouse wheel. But it does not look very userfriendly to me.

My idea is showing a icon or header bar in outer divs, and only if user is on icon or on header bar, he can move the div's.
Outside of these icon or header bar, the div does not move.

Unfortunately, to be honest, I'm somehow lost how to realize this switching on/off sortable function.

Any suggestions ?

Thx
Wolfgang

P.S. Latest jquery (v2) download from http://jquery.com/download/

Latest jquery-UI download from http://jqueryui.com/download/ with latest version, all checks off, then select RESIZABLE and SORTABLE, and Theme = "No Theme".

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset='utf-8'" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />
    <title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">@import url(./jquery-ui.min.css);</style>
    <script src="./jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#MainData" ).sortable({
                cancel: ".ui-state-disabled"
            });
            $( "#MainData" ).disableSelection();
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5em;

    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 99.9%;
    height: 99.9%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: none;
}

.Main {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 6rem;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

.MainData {
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    border: 1rem solid;
    border-color:#000;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 2rem;
}

.BoxResize {
    width: 25rem;
    height: 15.45rem;
    min-width: 25rem;
    min-height: 15.45rem;
    float: left;
    border: 0.05rem solid;
    border-color:#000;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem;
}
.BoxInner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
    </style> 
</head>

<body>

    <div class="Main" id="Main"> 
        <div class="MainData" id="MainData">

            <div class="BoxResize" id="BoxResize1">
                <div class="BoxInner" id="BoxInner">
                    <h1>Box 1</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut odio. Nam sed est. Nam a risus et est iaculis adipiscing. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer ut justo. In tincidunt viverra nisl. Donec dictum malesuada magna. Curabitur id nibh auctor tellus adipiscing pharetra. Fusce vel justo non orci semper feugiat. Cras eu leo at purus ultrices tristique.<br /><br /></p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut odio. Nam sed est. Nam a risus et est iaculis adipiscing. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer ut justo. In tincidunt viverra nisl. Donec dictum malesuada magna. Curabitur id nibh auctor tellus adipiscing pharetra. Fusce vel justo non orci semper feugiat. Cras eu leo at purus ultrices tristique.<br /><br /></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="BoxResize" id="BoxResize2">
                <div class="BoxInner" id="BoxInner">
                    <h1>Box 2</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut odio. Nam sed est. Nam a risus et est iaculis adipiscing. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer ut justo. In tincidunt viverra nisl. Donec dictum malesuada magna. Curabitur id nibh auctor tellus adipiscing pharetra. Fusce vel justo non orci semper feugiat. Cras eu leo at purus ultrices tristique.<br /><br /></p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut odio. Nam sed est. Nam a risus et est iaculis adipiscing. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer ut justo. In tincidunt viverra nisl. Donec dictum malesuada magna. Curabitur id nibh auctor tellus adipiscing pharetra. Fusce vel justo non orci semper feugiat. Cras eu leo at purus ultrices tristique.<br /><br /></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="BoxResize" id="BoxResize3">
                <div class="BoxInner" id="BoxInner">
                    <h1>Box 3</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut odio. Nam sed est. Nam a risus et est iaculis adipiscing. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer ut justo. In tincidunt viverra nisl. Donec dictum malesuada magna. Curabitur id nibh auctor tellus adipiscing pharetra. Fusce vel justo non orci semper feugiat. Cras eu leo at purus ultrices tristique.<br /><br /></p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut odio. Nam sed est. Nam a risus et est iaculis adipiscing. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer ut justo. In tincidunt viverra nisl. Donec dictum malesuada magna. Curabitur id nibh auctor tellus adipiscing pharetra. Fusce vel justo non orci semper feugiat. Cras eu leo at purus ultrices tristique.<br /><br /></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share the css as well which is required to reproduce this...

Comment: Main Topic updated with CSS

Comment: I [tried re-creating](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/wo0nc070/) whatever you're talking about with the shared code, but I don't even see a scrollbar. Hence voting to close. Maybe update the question/fiddle with the code required to reproduce this.

Comment: I will rewrite during today the question above with a full working html. Just give me some time.

Comment: Initial post adapted with a full working html file, showing this issue.